# Polynomial Multiplication using std::tuple using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Assuming I have a 2 tuples of representing coefficients of two polynomials, how do I compute there multiplication coefficients.
I want to accomplish this using template.

`mul_scalar()` multiplies value of tuple to a with the scalar.
I am trying to use this function to extend to polynomial case. By iterating over one tuple and using `mul_scalar()`

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility> 
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
mul_scalar(const T& lhs, const std::tuple<Tp...> rhs ) // Unused arguments are given no names.
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
mul_scalar(const T& lhs, const std::tuple<Tp...> rhs)
{
    std::cout << (std::get<I>(rhs))*lhs << " ";
    mul_scalar<I + 1, T, Tp...>(lhs, rhs);
}

template <std::size_t I = 0, template <typename ...> class Tup1, template <typename ...> class Tup2, typename ...A, typename ...B>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(A), void>::type
mul_poly(const Tup1<A...>& lhs, const Tup2<B...> rhs)
{
    mul_scalar(std::get<I>(lhs), rhs);
    //mul_poly(lhs, rhs); with I = I + 1
    // However I can't figure how to give other template args
}

int main(){
    auto poly_1 = std::make_tuple(2,1);
    auto poly_2 = std::make_tuple(3,4,5);
    mul_scalar(3,poly_1);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Expected output 6 8 10 3 4 5
    mul_poly(poly_1, poly_2);
}
```

Comment: strictly C++11 or C++14/C++17 are OK?

Comment: Would prefer C++11. But would be great if you could tell me other approaches as well.

Comment: Answer improved with a different approach example; hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive call is simple

```
mul_poly<I+1u>(lhs, rhs);
```

but you have to add the ground case

```
template <std::size_t I = 0, template <typename ...> class Tup1,
          template <typename ...> class Tup2, typename ...A, typename ...B>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(A), void>::type
    mul_poly (const Tup1<A...> &, const Tup2<B...> &)
 { }
```

> would be great if you could tell me other approaches as well

Bonus suggestion: if you can use C++17, you can avoid SFINAE and recursion, for `mul_scalar()`, using `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` (or `std::index_sequence_for`) and template folding as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ... Tp, std::size_t ... Is>
void mul_scalar_helper (T const & lhs, std::tuple<Tp...> const & rhs,
                        std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { ((std::cout << (std::get<Is>(rhs))*lhs << ' '), ...); }

template <typename T, typename ... Tp>
void mul_scalar (T const & lhs, std::tuple<Tp...> const & rhs)
 { mul_scalar_helper(lhs, rhs, std::index_sequence_for<Tp...>{}); }
```

For `mul_poly()` there isn't a great difference

```
template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
          template <typename ...> class Tup2,
          typename ... A, typename ... B, std::size_t ... Is>
void mul_poly_helper (Tup1<A...> const & lhs, Tup2<B...> const & rhs,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { (mul_scalar(std::get<Is>(lhs), rhs), ...); }

template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
          template <typename ...> class Tup2,
          typename ...A, typename ...B>
void mul_poly (Tup1<A...> const & lhs, Tup2<B...> const & rhs)
 { mul_poly_helper(lhs, rhs, std::index_sequence_for<A...>{}); }
```

Anyway... are you sure that `std::tuple` is the right container? Have you considered `std::array`?

**--- EDIT ---**

Following the liliscent's suggestion (thanks!) you can avoid the helper functions and `std::index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence_for` using `std::apply()` simply writing

```
template <typename T, typename ... Tp>
void mul_scalar (T const & lhs, std::tuple<Tp...> const & rhs)
 { std::apply([&](auto const & ... x){ ((std::cout << x*lhs << ' '), ...); }, rhs); }

template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
          template <typename ...> class Tup2,
          typename ...A, typename ...B>
void mul_poly (Tup1<A...> const & lhs, Tup2<B...> const & rhs)
 { std::apply([&](auto const & ... x){ (mul_scalar(x, rhs), ...); }, lhs); }
```

You can also write `mul_poly()` with a couple of `std::apply()`, without calling `mul_scalar()`

```
template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
          template <typename ...> class Tup2,
          typename ...A, typename ...B>
void mul_poly (Tup1<A...> const & lhs, Tup2<B...> const & rhs)
 { std::apply([&](auto const & ... x){
      (std::apply([x](auto const & ... y){ ((std::cout << x*y << ' '), ...); }, 
                  rhs), ...); }, lhs); }
```

Comment: In C++17, I'd use `std::apply` instead of `std::index_sequence` to avoid helper function boilerplate. Like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/X05YxHt1IdXN4iYq

Comment: @max66 Actually I am using it for different purpose. But I thought it would be easier to explain the problem with this example.

Comment: @liliscent - I'm still not used to `std::apply()` but you're right: is a lot simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeCollector - following a liliscent's suggestion, I've simplified a lot `mul_scalar()` and `mul_poly()`

Comment: @liliscent - hi can you explain this part? (f(tup_e),...); - how does the comma after f(tup_e) help here? seeing this for the first time

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti - The comma helps because it's an operator and, with ellipsis (`...`) after it, activate template folding (a C++17 new feature) over `tup_e`, a variadic list of argument. More details and examples in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).